# How to return local date in another language?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I return local date string in some other language and not in english?

I am using this:

```
new Date().toLocaleDateString()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change locale in JS. I'd suggest using [**MomentJS**](http://momentjs.com/) library for processing dates. With it your request can be solved as easily as...

```
var localLang = moment();
localLang.lang('fr');     // set this instance to use French
localLang.format('LLLL'); // dimanche 15 juillet 2012 11:01
```